# Return in try with resources. Is it correct behaviour of JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, specifications, try-with-resources

In the following code example I expect to have 1 as a return value of method `testM()`. But due to the exception in `TestAutoCloseable.close()` method I get unexpected behaviour.

My question is: "Is it a normal behaviour of JVM?"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProgrammerTwo programmerTwo = new ProgrammerTwo();
    System.out.println(programmerTwo.testM());
}

int testM() {
    try (TestAutoCloseable closable = new TestAutoCloseable()) {
        System.out.println("Do first return");
        return 1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("handled");
    }
    System.out.println("Do something, that shouldn't do if first return have happened");
    return 2;
}

static class TestAutoCloseable implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

Because if it is normal behaviour, we shouldn't use return or break statements in try with resources statement. It should be anti-pattern.

Comment: of course this is normal behaviour. as soon as the exception is thrown, you leave the try and go straight to the catch. This is not 'unwanted' or 'wrong' behavior. This is how it is designed.

Comment: This is normal, expected, and desirable behavior. It is why it makes sense to return from the `try` block. If it was the way you describe, then it would be an anti-pattern to return from the `try` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details of how the `try-with-resources` statement works are in [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) from the JLS. In your case, it is an *extended* `try-with-resources` since it has a `catch` clause as defined in the below quote (note the highlighted statement at the end).

> A try-with-resources statement with at least one catch clause and/or a finally clause is called an extended try-with-resources statement.
>
> The meaning of an extended try-with-resources statement:
>
> ```
> try ResourceSpecification
>      Block
> [Catches]
> [Finally]
> ```
>
> is given by the following translation to a basic try-with-resources statement nested inside a try-catch or try-finally or try-catch-finally statement:

```
try {
  try ResourceSpecification          <--- exception thrown in this basic try-with-resources
      Block
}
[Catches]
[Finally]
```

> The effect of the translation is to put the resource specification "inside" the try statement. **This allows a catch clause of an extended try-with-resources statement to catch an exception due to the automatic initialization or closing of any resource.**

This means that closing the resource occurs *within* the body of the outer `try` block, causing an exception to be thrown and handled in the `catch` block, and control resumes to the statements after the extended `try-with-resources` statement.

In effect, the whole method `testM` is equivalent to:

```
int testM() {
    try {
       final TestAutoCloseable closable = new TestAutoCloseable();
       Throwable #primaryExc = null;
       try {
           System.out.println("Do first return");
           return 1;
       } catch (Throwable #t) {
           #primaryExc = #t;
           throw #t;
       } finally {
           if (closable != null) {
              if (#primaryExc != null) {
                 try {
                    closable.close();
                 } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
                    #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
                 }
              } else {
                 closable.close();
              }
          }
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("handled");
    }
    System.out.println("Do something, that shouldn't do if first return have happened");
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: With or without this convenience, the method will either exit by throwing an exception, or proceed beyond the `return 1` line. Returning 1 despite the exception is nonsense in each case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Now I understand how it work after compilation. But semantically source code is not obvious. So it should be some anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words,When your try-with-resource block is exiting,an IOException is thrown (since you are throwing it from **close()**,so  value **1** has never been returned from the method,instead JVM moves to catch block because as per the rule,as soon as any exception happens then all the remaing code in try block does not get executed instead JVM moves to catch block.so now your catch block runs and then your remaining codes get executed